# Spring Boot configuration conventions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

For Spring Boot app, we use `application.yml` or `.properties` variant to write spring-specific app configuration. For example:

```
server:
  port: 7779

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: gateway
```

Is there some convention how to name application domain-specific configuration? Where to put this config: in same `application.yml` or it should be separate file? How to name those properties? Example

```
adder-service:
  max-number : 33
some-other:
  a:
    b: 44
```

Should we generate additionally `META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` for this app-specific config?

Comment: Same file, choose your prefixes wisely (I prefer having a common prefix which is typically the name of the app). https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is to think about configuration file as about a configuration structures with defaults:

```
myapp:
   myprop1: abc
   myprop2: xyz
```

The actual values come from the environment:

```
MYAPP_MYPROP1=abc
MYAPP_MYPROP2=xyz
```

Use [type-safe configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-java-bean-binding) in code with an application specific prefix.

```
@ConfigurationProperties("myapp")
class MyAppProperties {

    private String myprop1;
    private String myprop2;

    // getters & setters ...
}
```

If the configuration is specific fo a particular deployment scenario, put it into a separate file managed by a Spring profile eg. `application-aws.yml` etc.

```
spring.profiles.active=aws
```